# How to createRequest by using guzzleHttp?

Tags: php, request, guzzle

I used GuzzleHttp, I have created request following commands:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

$url = 'http://localhost/api/get_data?token=123456';
$client = new Client();
$request = $client->createRequest('GET', $url, []);
```

But `error`:

```
Argument 3 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::request() must be of the type array, string given, called in /home/datnq/www/slim/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php on line 88 and defined
```

Why did I miss ? I think parameters are right!

Comment: I get the same thing. Its using the magic method that thinks the HTTP verb is the function name, rather than the first argument. I think its a bug. EDIT - we are looking at the wrong docs. See here: http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: I checked class Client. I find the first argument is  always `method`. Don't have any method `createRequest`. So order of arguments  confuse. The docs are wrong :(

Comment: The  docs are accurate for 5.x. Check the link above for the latest docs.

Comment: Thanks @EricCopeE. It's good, now

Answer (score 4):

The reason why is that usage is for Guzzle 5.x, however, that message is most likely from using 6.x versions. I'd post a link to the 6.x version of the docs, but all I can find is http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html
and it isn't semantically versioned.